# How to calculate the days belonging to an ISO based week number

Tags: java, week-number, date

I have an ISO based week number that is calculated using the following Java 8 LocalDate API

```
int weekNumOfYear = LocalDate#get(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
```

Given the year, and the week number (eg, 201927),How could I calculate the start day and end day for this week(201917)?

I am Using `Calendar` class for this problem, but not sure it is correct(especially, whether is has followed the ISO format)

> Update： The following code doesn't work correctly for 201953, there is
>   no 53th week for 2019

```
@Test
    public void testGetWeekDays() {
        Integer year = 2019;
        Integer week = 27;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Use ISO format
        cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);

        cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        String beginDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
        String endDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(beginDate);
        System.out.println(endDate);
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V.. I agree, Java 8 Date/Time API are much better, both design and performance,compared with old Date/Calendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `with` to get start day and end day of week

```
System.out.println(localDate.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
System.out.println(localDate.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
```

If you want to get start day and end day from week number, then use [ISO_WEEK_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE)

```
LocalDate startDay = LocalDate.parse("2019-W26-1", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE);

LocalDate endDay = LocalDate.parse("2019-W26-7", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE);
```

> One digit for the day-of-week. The value run from Monday (1) to Sunday (7).

Comment: I just have a week number in hand, eg, 201926(not a particular day)

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool, that is perfect, thanks! I have coded it using the old Calendar class, could you please help take a look if it is correct(especially, whether it follows the ISO format)

Comment: it seems good for me, but why don't you try executing it @Tom

Comment: @Deadpool I am trying it, and testing some corner cases.

Comment: my code has one problem: for `201953`, it produces incorrect result(but 53 week is invalid for 2019), your code works well(throws exception)

Comment: are you still on java 7? @Tom

Comment: I am using java 8, but not quite good at java 8 time API, :-). It is a good chance for me to work and familiar with this API,:-)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> Given the year, and the week number (eg, 201927),I could I calculate the start day and end day for this week(201917)?

```
YearWeek              // Represent a particular week of a week-based year.
.of(                  // Factory method, rather than calling `new`. 
    2019 ,            // The number of the desired week-based year ( *not* calendar year! ).
    26                // Week of the year, 1 through 52 or 53. 
)
.atDay(               // Generate a `LocalDate` object for a day within this week.
    DayOfWeek.MONDAY  // Specify the day-of-week.
)                     // Generate a `LocalDate` for the first day of this week.
.plusDays( 6 )        // Generate a `LocalDate` representing the last day of this week.
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra* — `YearWeek`

Working with standard weeks is much easier with the [`org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html)  class provided in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. That project adds functionality to the modern *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

If you have an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string representing a [standard week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), parse.

```
String input = "2019-W27";
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( input);
```

> yw.toString(): 2019-W27

A standard week begins with Monday. The `YearWeek` object can generate a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) for any day in the week. Specify a day using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
LocalDate ld = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
```

> ld.toString(): 2019-07-01

To get the rest of the week, add a day over and over.

```
LocalDate nextDay = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2019-07-02

To get the end of the week, add six.

```
LocalDate nextDay = ld.plusDays( 6 ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2019-07-07

Or get fancy using Java streams. Generate a stream by calling [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)).

```
Stream < LocalDate > stream = ld.datesUntil ( ld.plusWeeks ( 1 ) );
List < LocalDate > dates = stream.collect ( Collectors.toList () );
```

> dates.toString(): [2019-07-01, 2019-07-02, 2019-07-03, 2019-07-04, 2019-07-05, 2019-07-06, 2019-07-07]

By the way, the standard way to represent a day-of-week within a standard week is to append a hyphen and number 1-7.

> 2019-W26-1  =  Monday
>
> 2019-W26-2  =  Tuesday
>
> …
>
> 2019-W26-7  =  Sunday